# What is the best way to make an orbiting button

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I would like to make something like this:
https://youtu.be/W3O0077GMlo
And I would like for the rotating circle (moon in this video) to act as a button.

What is the best way to do this performance wise?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Do you already have existing code? Also have a look at [Transform.rotate](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Transform/Transform.rotate.html) and the [RotationTransition](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RotationTransition-class.html). If this is your first animation in Flutter, have a look at [Introduction to animations in Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations).

Comment: Hi Niklas, thank you! I am new to flutter. I read everything and I tried to rotate the container with transform but it was stuttering. I dont have a code, I deleted it. Right now I am trying to do it with spriteWidged. I want the rotation to look smooth.

Comment: Did your animation stutter on the emulator on the release version on your mobile phone? I'll write an answer with a short example.

Comment: It stutter on my my phone, note 9. Everything is updated, no issues with flutter. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`RotationTransition`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RotationTransition-class.html) inside a [`Stack`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) widget to create the rotating animation. Inside the `Stack`set the `alignment` to center, and wrap your rotating widget inside an [`Align`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html). Set the alignment attribute of the `Align` widget to `Alignment.topCenter` or any outer alignment.

Remember to deploy on **release** to your phone to make sure the animations are running **smooth**.

---

Quick standalone code example:

[image: Demo]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: SizedBox(width: 300.0, height: 300.0, child: OrbitingButton()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OrbitingButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OrbitingButtonState createState() => _OrbitingButtonState();
}

class _OrbitingButtonState extends State<OrbitingButton>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(vsync: this);

    controller.repeat(min: 0.0, max: 1.0, period: Duration(seconds: 1));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        RotationTransition(
          turns: controller,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              height: 30.0,
              width: 30.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Button'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will test the code when I get home.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you Niklas!